# RIP author Greg Bear

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

The death of Greg Bear on November 19th was announced on his [website](https://gregbear.com/news.php#420).

> **Rest In Peace**
>
> 11/20/2022
>
> Greg passed away peacefully yesterday, surrounded by his loving
> family. He will be greatly missed by those who were fortunate enough
> to know him personally, as well as by countless readers around the
> world.
>
> Greg Bear 8/20/1951–11/19/2022

Answer (score 10):

Bear was author of more than 50 books, including the Forge of God series, The Way series, and the Darwin series.

He was nominated for multiple awards, including the Arthur C Clarke award for Eon and Darwin's Children, the Hugo for Darwin's Radio and the Forge of God, and the Nebula for the Forge of God.

He won the Nebula for Moving Mars, and both Nebula and Hugo awards for shorter works.

In addition Bear was one of the founders of the San Diego Comic Con.

Answer (score 3):

I also fondly remember his two novel fantasy series, [The Infinity Concerto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Infinity_Concerto) and [The Serpent Mage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serpent_Mage_(Greg_Bear)). They were centered on the coming of age of a young man into the leading mage of modern-day Earth. They come from early in Greg Bear's career but already show his promise.

If you enjoy modern takes on fantasy, they are quite readable if a bit slow at the start.